# Scala play api json com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]

Tags: json, scala, parsing

```
  val nodestring = redisScalaConnector.hget("SPARKDTF", uuid)
  println(nodestring)
  val nodestringparsed: String = nodestring match {
    case None            => ""
    case Some(s: String) => s
  }


  val nodejson = Json.parse(nodestringparsed)
        println(nodejson)
        val delimiter = nodejson.\("delimiter").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val tableName = nodejson.\("tablename").get.toString().replace("\"", "").toLowerCase()
        val keySpace = nodejson.\("keyspace").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val hostIP = nodejson.\("sourceFileHost").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val fileLoc = nodejson.\("sourceFileLoc").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val filename = nodejson.\("filename").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val connectiontype = nodejson.\("connectiontype").get.toString().replace("\"", "")
        val header = nodejson.\("header").get.toString().replace("\"", "")

    val AutoCreateService = new AutoCreateService(sc)

    var tablequery: Seq[String] = nodejson.\\("tablequery").map(_.as[String])
    println(tablequery)
    AutoCreateService.CqlQueryProcessing(tablequery)

    var metadataquery: Seq[String] = nodejson.\\("metadataquery").map(_.as[String])
    AutoCreateService.CqlQueryProcessing(metadataquery)
```

my json below:

```
{
  "delimiter": "\t",
  "sourceFileHost": "10.87.88.123",
  "sourceFilePort": "50070",
  "sourceFileLoc": "/nandha/U_Fin_Group.tab",
  "header": false,
  "keyspace": "jofi",
  "connectiontype": "HDFS",
  "filename": "U_Fin_Group.tab",
  "tablename": "fin_group",
  "tablequery": [
    "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS jofi WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1' } AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jofi.fin_group(acc_no text,branch text,fin_id text,PRIMARY KEY (fin_id))"
  ],
  "metadataquery": [
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jofi.metadatatable(colname text,tablename text,checkcondition text,coltype text,filename text,isnull text,maxval text,minval text,sourcecol int,PRIMARY KEY (colname, tablename,filename))",
    "INSERT INTO jofi.metadatatable(colname, tablename, checkcondition, coltype, filename, isnull, maxval, minval, sourcecol)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [
      "fin_id",
      "fin_group",
      "",
      "text",
      "U_Fin_Group.tab",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "0"
    ],
    "INSERT INTO jofi.metadatatable(colname, tablename, checkcondition, coltype, filename, isnull, maxval, minval, sourcecol)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [
      "acc_no",
      "fin_group",
      "",
      "text",
      "U_Fin_Group.tab",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "2"
    ],
    "INSERT INTO jofi.metadatatable(colname, tablename, checkcondition, coltype, filename, isnull, maxval, minval, sourcecol)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [
      "branch",
      "fin_group",
      "",
      "text",
      "U_Fin_Group.tab",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: my json is here.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error cause the value im reading from redis is the key value i have given is wrong. so the value reurns error and it has no value to read. so the JSON parser is looking to read something but it doesnt got the input correctly. tried with declaring value and input correctly. it worked perfect for me. there's nothing wrong with the code.